# Custom distance loss function in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I want to implement the following distance loss function in pytorch. I was following this https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-loss-functions/29387/4 thread from the pytorch forum

```
np.linalg.norm(output - target)
# where output.shape = [1, 2] and target.shape = [1, 2]
```

So I have implemented the loss function like this

```
def my_loss(output, target):    
    loss = torch.tensor(np.linalg.norm(output.detach().numpy() - target.detach().numpy()))
    return loss
```

with this loss function, calling backwards gives runtime error

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

My entire code looks like this

```
model = nn.Linear(2, 2)

x = torch.randn(1, 2)
target = torch.randn(1, 2)
output = model(x)

loss = my_loss(output, target)
loss.backward()   <----- Error here

print(model.weight.grad)
```

PS: I am aware of the pairwise loss of pytorch but due to some limitation of it, I have to implement it myself.

Following the pytorch source code I have tried the following,

```
class my_function(torch.nn.Module): # forgot to define backward()
    def forward(self, output, target):

        loss = torch.tensor(np.linalg.norm(output.detach().numpy() - target.detach().numpy()))
        return loss

model = nn.Linear(2, 2)
x = torch.randn(1, 2)
target = torch.randn(1, 2)
output = model(x)

criterion = my_function()

loss = criterion(output, target)


loss.backward()
print(model.weight.grad)
```

And I get the Run time error

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

How can I implement the loss function correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because, in the loss function, you are detaching tensors. You had to detach because you wanted to use `np.linalg.norm`. This breaks the graph and you get the error that tensors don't have grad fn.

You can replace

`loss = torch.tensor(np.linalg.norm(output.detach().numpy() - target.detach().numpy()))`

by torch operations as

`loss = torch.norm(output-target)`

This should work fine.

Comment: so all need to use torch operations at all time I guess ? do I need to write the backward pass ?

Comment: You don't need to write the backward pass yourself as long as you use all torch functions and PyTorch's automatic differentiation (calling backward function).

Comment: As @akshayk07 said use torch functions that are differentiable and that will make sure the computation graph differentiable and the `.backward` would work